# Confusing std::string::c_str() behavior in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl, constants, stdstring

I'm sure I've done something wrong, but for the life of me I can't figure out what! Please consider the following code:

```
cerr<<el.getText()<<endl;
cerr<<el.getText().c_str()<<endl;
cerr<<"---"<<endl;
const char *value = el.getText().c_str();
cerr<<"\""<<value<<"\""<<endl;
field.cdata = el.getText().c_str();
cerr<<"\""<<field.cdata<<"\""<<endl;
```

`el` is an XML element and `getText` returns a std::string. As expected, `el.getText()` and `el.getText().c_str()` print the same value. However, `value` is set to `""` - that is, the empty string - when it assigned the result of `c_str()`. This code had been written to set `field.cdata=value`, and so was clearing it out. After changing it to the supposedly-identical expression `value` is set from, it works fine and the final line prints the expected value.

Since `el` is on the stack, I thought I might have been clobbering it - but even after `value` is set, the underlying value in `el` is still correct.

My next thought was that there was some weird compiler-specific issue with assigning things to const pointers, so I wrote the following:

```
std::string thing = "test";
std::cout << thing << std::endl;
std::cout << thing.c_str() << std::endl;
const char* value = thing.c_str();
std::cout << value << std::endl;
```

As expected, I get 'test' three times.

So now I have no clue what is going on. It would seem obvious that there is something strange going on in my program that's not happening in the sample, but I don't know what it is and I'm out of ideas about how to keep looking. Can somebody enlighten me, or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does `getText` return the string by value? If so, your problem lies in such lines as `const char *value = el.getText().c_str();`, which cause a dangling pointer at the end of that very line.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? `getText()` does return by value. Are you saying that the return-by-val creates a copy of the string, which immediately goes out of scope and is destroyed - but not before I got a (now-invalid) pointer to it?

Comment: @chris You were correct; the string is returned by value so it goes out of scope immediately and the pointer ceases to be valid. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Accept the existing answer. It already explains what I said in my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that `el.getText()` is returning a temporary `string` object.  When that object is destroyed the pointer returned by `c_str()` is no longer valid (keep in mind that that are other ways the pointer returned by `c_str()` can be invalidated, too).

The temporary object will be destroyed at the end of the full expression it's created in (which is generally at the semi-colon in your example above).

You may be able to solve your problem with something like the following:

```
const char *value = strdup(el.getText().c_str());
```

which creates a copy of the string as a raw `char` array in dynamically allocated memory.  You then become responsible for calling `free()` on that pointer at some point when that data is no longer needed.

Comment: `getText` is implemented as `std::string getText() const { return _text; }`. So I think it's a real copy of the string. However, the `el` object goes out of scope and it's on the stack, so would the pointer become invalid? It still doesn't explain why I was getting an empty string when its source was still valid and in scope.

Comment: @Robert, the string returned by `getText` is a temporary *copy* of the string in `e1`. Since the source is a temporary, the pointer becomes invalid when the temporary becomes invalid - at the first semi-colon.

Comment: @Robert It's not `el` that's going out of scope, but the `std::string` returned by the `getText()` function. That return value goes out of scope at the end of the assignment statement where you assign it to `value`. Thereafter `value` points to a deallocated object, and accessing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Well, keeping the returned string as a local variable is more C++-style than copying a C-string and calling free on it. Good C++-style code should contain almost no malloc, free, delete, raw pointers, raw arrays, ... (as long as there is a good C++ way to handle it, like smart pointers and stuff like that; the same counts for std::string)

Comment: @leemes: true enough, but sometimes you're getting data that needs to work with existing C structures or interfaces.  I guess I assumed that's what was intended/needed here.

Comment: @MichaelBurr What I meant was the following: Why not just store the `std::string` in a variable which lifetime at least is as long as we need its C-string representation? Maybe this can't easily be done here. If the lifetime of the `field` (where the C-string is needed) isn't well-defined, we can't proper free the C-string anyway, so keeping a `std::string` instead of manually freeing the C-string afterwards should be the same "difficulty".